# How to set logo in center of splash screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to have a logo image splash screen centered with layout_width and layout_height in dp.
The logo image is taken directly from the logo folder at `@mipmap/ic_launcher`.

**Problem:**
I am unable to center the logo image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/launch_background"
>
  <ImageView 
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  >
  </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your `ImageView`

Comment: You should use ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout for that.

Comment: Use relative layout instead of Framelayout.

Comment: @Christilyn yea that exactly what i wanted. maybe u can post it in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your `ImageView` to center it within a `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/launch_background"
>
  <ImageView 
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  >
  </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/launch_background"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `ConstraintLayout`

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```